# Django - Count a subset of related models - Need to annotate count of active Coupons for each Item

Tags: sql, django, orm, count, aggregates

I have a Coupon model that has some fields to define if it is active, and a custom manager which returns only live coupons. Coupon has an FK to Item.

In a query on Item, I'm trying to annotate the number of active coupons available. However, the Count aggregate seems to be counting all coupons, not just the active ones.

```
# models.py
class LiveCouponManager(models.Manager):
    """
    Returns only coupons which are active, and the current
    date is after the active_date (if specified) but before the valid_until
    date (if specified).
    """
    def get_query_set(self):
        today = datetime.date.today()
        passed_active_date = models.Q(active_date__lte=today) | models.Q(active_date=None)
        not_expired = models.Q(valid_until__gte=today) | models.Q(valid_until=None)
        return super(LiveCouponManager,self).get_query_set().filter(is_active=True).filter(passed_active_date, not_expired)

class Item(models.Model):
    # irrelevant fields

class Coupon(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    active_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    valid_until = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    # more fields

    live = LiveCouponManager() # defined first, should be default manager

# views.py
# this is the part that isn't working right
data = Item.objects.filter(q).distinct().annotate(num_coupons=Count('coupon', distinct=True))
```

The `.distinct()` and `distinct=True` bits are there for other reasons - the query is such that it will return duplicates. That all works fine, just mentioning it here for completeness.

The problem is that `Count` is including inactive coupons that are filtered out by the custom manager.

Is there any way I can specify that `Count` should use the `live` manager?

---

#### EDIT

The following SQL query does exactly what I need:

```
SELECT data_item.title, COUNT(data_coupon.id) FROM data_item LEFT OUTER JOIN data_coupon ON (data_item.id=data_coupon.item_id)
WHERE (
    (is_active='1') AND 
    (active_date <= current_timestamp OR active_date IS NULL) AND
    (valid_until >= current_timestamp OR valid_until IS NULL)
)
GROUP BY data_item.title
```

At least on sqlite. Any SQL guru feedback would be greatly appreciated - I feel like I'm programming by accident here. Or, even better, a translation back to Django ORM syntax would be awesome.

Comment: Did you try `use_for_related_fields`? (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types)

Comment: There's a big "DO NOT FILTER AWAY ANY RESULTS IN THIS TYPE OF MANAGER SUBCLASS" disclaimer - kinda scares me away from trying it. I'm thinking I may need to take a raw SQL approach, which I'd really rather avoid if at all possible.

Comment: tried `use_for_related_fields` anyway, didn't help.

Comment: Before anyone says as much, I know that 'data' is a lame name for an app.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else has the same problem, here's how I've gotten it to work:

```
Items = Item.objects.filter(q).distinct().extra(

            select={"num_coupons":
                     """
                     SELECT  COUNT(data_coupon.id) FROM  data_coupon
                     WHERE (
                         (data_coupon.is_active='1') AND 
                         (data_coupon.active_date <= current_timestamp OR data_coupon.active_date IS NULL) AND
                         (data_coupon.valid_until >= current_timestamp OR data_coupon.valid_until IS NULL) AND
                         (data_coupon.data_id = data_item.id)
                     )
                     """
                    },).order_by(order_by)
```

I don't know that I consider this a 'correct' answer - it completely duplicates my custom manager in a possibly non portable way (I'm not sure how portable `current_timestamp` is), but it does work.

Comment: Just an FYI - it seems that once you use `extra`, you cannot add any other `annotate` calls, any further annotations must be done in SQL as well (just add them to the existing `select` dict).

Comment: Hi Chris, did you ever figure out a more Django ORM-ish way to solve this problem or did you stick with the .extra() method above?

Comment: No, this was part of a pretty short term project so I pretty much moved on to other things once I got this working. Never had a problem with it though, seemed to perform OK and passed all tests, etc.

Comment: I've had to do that before as well, and I think it's a reasonable solution

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your custom manager actually get's called? You set your manager as Model.live, but you query the normal manager at Model.objects.

Have you tried the following?

```
data = Data.live.filter(q)...
```

Comment: Data is another model, which I mistakenly represented as 'Item' in my example. It has an FK to Coupon. Only Coupon has a custom manager called 'live'